# Firebase.Firestore is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with a React Native app that we are changing from Firebase Realtime Database to Firebase Firestore, but when I go to run the app on Expo I recieve this error:
*TypeError:TypeError: firebase.firestore is not a function. (In 'firebase'firestore()', 'firebase.firestore' is undefined)

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, Button, Picker} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    state = {
        email: ""
    };

    //constructor that saves the states of string "student" and array "students" empty values
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            student: '',
            students: [],
            selectedStudent: '',
            studentItem: ''
        }
    }

    //once page is initialized, the child table "students" of the root database location
    //(.ref().child("students")) will be read once, and if the "students" table exists in the database,
    //each value in that table will be stored as a "student" string, and populate the "students" array
    componentDidMount() {
        console.disableYellowBox = true;

        firebase.firestore().collection('Students').get().then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc);
            })
        });

        // firebase.database().ref().child("students").once("value", snapshot => {
        //  const data = snapshot.val()
        //  if(data) {
        //      const initStudents = [];
        //      Object.keys(data).forEach(student => initStudents.push(data[student]));
        //      this.setState({
        //          students: initStudents
        //      })
        //  }
        // });
    }
```

Comment: Where did you include the SDK for Firestore?

Comment: Is that what I am missing?

Comment: You have to include the Firestore SDK like any other Firebase product SDK.  If you didn't do that, you'll get that error message.

Comment: How do I do that on React Native?

Comment: I have the firebaseConfig in my App.js if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

By way of example, a part of my firestore module - I abstract as much of the firestore details away from my app as possible:

```
import "@firebase/app";
import firebase from "@firebase/app";
import "@firebase/firestore";
import { config } from "../constants";

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// note schema is custom and local

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const fdb = firebase.firestore();
fdb.enablePersistence({ synchorizeTabs: true });

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// routines

export const fetchRecord = (tablePath, Id, ref = null, transaction = null) => {
  const db = ref ? ref : fdb;

  const docRef = db.collection(tablePath).doc(Id);

  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      if (transaction) return transaction.get(docRef); // note early return
      else return docRef.get();
    })
    .then(docSnapshot => {
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        return Promise.resolve({
          ...docSnapshot.data(),
          Id: docSnapshot.id,
          ref: docSnapshot.ref
        });
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(null);
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: oh, the 'ref' parameter - I use a hierarchical database structure, and .collection() *defaults* to 'root', but *can* be from any document.  and "Transaction" is just a convenient way for me to chain accesses in a transaction.